# Generate Razor view with multiple models in model class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So basically I have a model for all my recipes and I want to create a view that shows a list of all the recipes with a boolean if the current logged in user can edit the recipe. I've made a Presentation Model to do this. However, when I click 'Add View' in the controller and generate a new view with this presentation model, the view only shows the boolean, fields of 'recipe'. What should I do to generate a view with the bool and all fields of 'recipe'.

Model 'Recipe':

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ReceptenApp.Models
{
public class Recept
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Cook { get; set; }
}
}
```

Presentation Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ReceptenApp.Models.PresentationModels
{
public class PMReceptListItem
{
    public PMReceptListItem()
    {
        recept = new ReceptWithCats();
    }
    public ReceptWithCats recept { get; set; }
    public bool ShowEdit { get; set; }
}
}
```

View after generating it:

```
@model IEnumerable<ReceptenApp.Models.PresentationModels.PMReceptListItem>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
   <tr>
       <th>
           @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShowEdit)
       </th>
       <th></th>
   </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShowEdit)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your view is listing all the  Recept's, Let's update your presentation model(view model) to reflect that. We will also create a new viewmodel (*`ReceptViewModel`*) to represent the `Recept` entity. We will add `ReceptList`  in the `ReceptListViewModel` which a List of our new ReceptViewModel so that we can pass a list of Recept's to the view.

```
public class ReceptViewModel
{
   public int Id {set;get;}
   public string Title {set;get;}
   public string Description {set;get;}
   public string Cook {set;get;}
}
public class ReceptListViewModel
{
    public PMReceptListItem()
    {
        ReceptList = new List<ReceptViewModel>();
    }
    public List<ReceptViewModel>  ReceptList { get; set; }
    public bool ShowEdit { get; set; }
}
```

and in your GET action,read the data from your db and load to an object of our `ReceptListViewModel`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var vm= new ReceptListViewModel();
  vm.ReceptList = db.Recepts.Select(x=>new ReceptViewModel { 
                                           Id=s.Id, 
                                           Title=x.Title,
                                           Description=x.Description,
                                           Cook=x.Cook }).ToList();
  vm.ShowEdit = true ; //Set this value based on your condition
  return View(vm);
}
```

and in your GET view

```
@model List<ReceptListViewModel>
<h2>List of Recepts</h2>
<table>
@foreach(var r in Model.ReceptList)
{
 <tr>
    <td>@r.Title</td>
    <td>@r.Description</td>
    <td>@r.Cook</td>
    @if(Model.ShowEdit)
    {
     <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit",new { id=r.Id})</td>
     <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete","Delete",new { id=r.Id})</td>
    }
 </tr>
}
</table>
```